# find outliers and set them NA

Tags: r, outliers

I have a fairly large vector of about 4 million rows. The problem is that an external source altered the sensor data which produced a lot of outliers. I detected more than 90% of those. But now I am left with the last 10% of outliers which I can not find an approriate way to set them to NA. I don't want to delete them, just set them to NA.

[image]

This plot shows 100000 values. It does not look like this everywhere in the TS. Sometimes there are no outliers left, sometimes it looks like this. Which means I need an approach where I can find those outliers without setting data to NA that are not outliers.

I tried different packages (tsoutliers for example) without having much of a success.

Is there a package or a method out there that can find all or at least most of the outliers seen in the plot?

Comment: How do you want to define an "outlier", I ask because there are several ways to do it, and in order to answers one must know what would be an "outlier" in this case.

Comment: That is pretty hard to answer. What I am doing at the moment to the outliers that are already NA in this plot, is to compare the median of a 500 value window minus the data point itself, with the standard deviation of the 500 value window. But to do something similar with this without loosing "real" data is where I am failing.

Comment: Outlier is such a subjective term. What do you consider to be an outlier? IQR, N * Standard deviation, Median absolute deviation, and other such metrics are assuming normal distributions. Time series decomposition might be able to do a better job but nothing you do will be perfect. Maybe clustering could also help, where you can play with both in-cluster distance and in-cluster frequency, or between-clusters distance...but still, will not be perfect

Comment: As @SantiagoHurtado says, there is no fire-and-forget method. You need to get your definition of an outlier first, only then can you start removing them.

Comment: It may be usefull to use a movile window as you say, but to use Point > median+3*IQR , to define an outlier. I think that it is better than use standar deviation. 
Chass in case, IQR is percentil 0.75 - percentil 0.25

Comment: Another thought: if it is primarily for a presentation you could also think about plotting a median and/or mean.

Comment: I will have a look at all of this. Thanks! Will take some time though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to define outliers you could first pass a model which will define what are the "normal" values with a certain percent of confidence. This model can be moving average, `arima`, (here) `ets`, or many others...

```
library(fpp2)
dat <- c(1:50,10,52:100)+rnorm(100, sd=5)
fit <- ets(dat) # working with any model example auto.arima(dat)
upper <- fitted(fit) + 1.96*sqrt(fit$sigma2) #1.96 for 95% confidence interval
lower <- fitted(fit) - 1.96*sqrt(fit$sigma2) #1.96 for 95% confidence interval
plot(dat, type="n", ylim=range(lower,upper))
polygon(c(time(dat),rev(time(dat))), c(upper,rev(lower)), 
        col=rgb(0,0,0.6,0.2), border=FALSE)
lines(dat)
lines(fitted(fit),col='red')
out <- (dat < lower | dat > upper)
points(time(dat)[out], dat[out], pch=19)
```

This will give you a chart where the outliers are identified, and the confidence intervals shown.
[image: outlier identification with exponential model]
You can then remove the outliers like so:

```
dat[out] <- NA #removing outliers
```

Please note that how many outliers you find will depend on the model you choose. For example with `auto.arima`:
[image: auto.arima]

EDIT: this is based on Rob Hyndman's post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/154392/86187)

Comment: This looks really interesting. On a first test I bumped into one problem. It seems this approach doesn't really like NA values in the time series.

Comment: Okay. Nevermind. was only the plot command who could not cope with the NA's. This works really well!

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the plots don't like NA's, you could remove them first using `dat <- dat[!is.na(dat)]` for plotting

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define an outlier as Sotos says. Providing that you consider to be an outlier a data out of range mean +- N*standard_dev then it is easy to numerically identify them

Comment: Which is dangerous If your data does not follow a normal distribution. Gaussian filters in general will not work here.

Comment: That is how I would define my outliers and how I did it before. The problem with this approach is, if I want to find outliers pretty close to the actual data, I will remove this "real" data together with the outliers. In my case it was 1* standard deviation. Which, as mentioned removed 90% of the outliers. But now I am stuck at getting closer to 100%.

Comment: I remember an exercise in class about LASSO regression and outliers, have a look at this. I think LASSO regression can be usefull to detect outliers